# for loop iteration with command substitution

Tags: bash

I'm trying to iterate through a list of IP's contained in a config file, but I need to cut lines, as I only need the IP and conf=/path/to/file, so I can throw those into an array or variable for further processing.

The problem is when adding a pipe to "cut -d$'\n' -f1,3" to the command substitution the for loop will only iterate one pass on the IP's in the "check" array list.    DESIRED RESULTS AT BOTTOM:

```
check=(     
"192.168.0.50"     
"192.168.0.100"     
"192.168.0.150"      
"192.168.0.200"     
)    
for i in "${check[@]}"; do    
ip="$i"    

# config=$(grep -A2 "$ip" /home/user/D1/serverfault/config_file)     
config=$(grep -A2 "$ip" /home/user/D1/serverfault/config_file | cut -d$'\n' -f1,3)     

    if [ -z "$config" ]; then     
        echo "$ip NOT IN CONFIG"    

    else    
        echo "$config"    

    fi    
done    

###  config_file contents ###    

192.168.0.50     
255.255.255.0    
conf=/path/to/company/app/server001     
logging=yes    
-----     
192.168.0.100    
255.255.255.0    
conf=/path/to/company/app/cluster     
logging=yes    
-----    
192.168.0.50    
255.255.255.0    
conf=/path/to/company/app/server005     
logging=yes     
-----     
192.168.0.150    
255.255.255.0    
conf=/path/to/company/app/server006     
logging=yes     

DESIRED RESULTS 2 passes produced in results for 192.168.0.50     

192.168.0.50     
conf=/path/to/company/app/server001     
-----     
192.168.0.50   
conf=/path/to/company/app/server005    
-----      
192.168.0.100      
conf=/path/to/company/app/cluster       
-----    
192.168.0.150    
conf=/path/to/company/app/server006     


Please tell me how I can fix these.
```

Comment: i think xargs will do this

Answer (score 0):

Might be simpler to use `awk` to process such a file?

The `line` variable controls the IP address output. The script matches the IP address lines, but only prints out the first line. If the line processed begins with "conf=" then that line is printed and the "-----" line).

```
awk 'BEGIN{IP_line=1}
        /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ && IP_line==1 {
            print
            IP_line=2
        }
        /^conf=/ {
            print
            print "-----"
            IP_line=1
        }' /home/user/D1/serverfault/config_file
```